# Can't figure out what is wrong with my Brackets_checker program

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to compile with Eclipse I have next errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at scanner_io.Brackets_checker.main(Brackets_checker.java:21)
```

```
package scanner_io;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Brackets_checker {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 0;
    Scanner sc;
    char c ;
    boolean open = false;
    try {
      sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
      int i = 0;
      c = sc.next().charAt(i);
      while (c != '\n') {
        c = sc.next().charAt(i);

        if (c == '(') {
          k++;
          open = true;
        }
        if (c == ')' && open == true) {
          k--;
          open = false;
        }

        i++;
      }

      sc.close();
      if (k == 0)
        System.out.println("OK !");
      else
        System.out.println("NOT OK !");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error when compiling or when running it?

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) keeps eating elements, and you are getting a new element each time you invoke `c = sc.next().charAt(i);`

This means that if you have for example the tokens `Test is going wrong`, you will produce the characters that will be assigned to `c`: `T, s, i, n` - this is NOT what you are after most likely.

Instead, have a `String` variable `currentToken`, and iterate on its characters:

For example:

```
String currentToken = sc.next()
for (int i = 0; i < currentToken.length(); i++) {
    c = currentToken.charAt(i)
}
```

You should also use [`Scanner#hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) before invoking `next()`, it's safer, also verify your returned `String` (`currentToken` in above example) is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong:

```
c = sc.next().charAt(i);
```

You read a String from the file and get the i'th character from it.
The next time you call `c = sc.next().charAt(i)`, you get the i'th character of the next String, which means you only read one character from each String and skip all the rest.

You should store `sc.next()` in a String variable and iterate over the characters of that String before you call `sc.next()` again.

And `c != '\n'` is not a good stopping condition. You should check instead if the last call to `sc.next()` returned null.

Come to think of it, if you expect your entire input to be in one line, just call `String s = sc.nextLine();` one time and process the characters of `s`.